# Is there a max number of requests an Asp.net mvc 3 application can handle and what happens it's exceeded?

Tags: sql-server, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an application where you can select entries in a table to be updated.  You can select 50 and hit 'send it' and it will send all 50 as 50 individual ajax calls, each of which calls controller X that updates the database table Y.  The user said they selected 25 but I see 12 in the logs and no trace of the other 13.  I was wondering if maybe I hit some limit with the number of requests or the length of the queue.  Any Ideas?

(Running this locally it had no problem with 50-100 being sent at once it just took like 2 seconds for all of them to finally callback).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question cannot really be answered as there's no "hard limit" that would cause your ajax calls to be lost.  However, overloading the server (if you only have one) can cause requests to be queued up and/or take a long time which in turn may cause requests to timeout (depending on your settings).  Chances are if you are making 50 ajax calls instead of just one then there is some room for optimization there and I'm not sure that classifies as premature.

In the end, I think the most and best advice you will get is to profile and load test your code and hardware to be sure otherwise we're all just guessing.